Finding car fleets depending on speed and positions
I' currently trying to solve a leetcode question 853. Car Fleet with the following description
There are n cars going to the same destination along a one-lane road. The destination is target miles away.
You are given two integer array position and speed, both of length n, where position[i] is the position of the ith car and speed[i] is the speed of the ith car (in miles per hour).
A car can never pass another car ahead of it, but it can catch up to it and drive bumper to bumper at the same speed. The faster car will slow down to match the slower car's speed. The distance between these two cars is ignored (i.e., they are assumed to have the same position).
A car fleet is some non-empty set of cars driving at the same position and same speed. Note that a single car is also a car fleet.
If a car catches up to a car fleet right at the destination point, it will still be considered as one car fleet.
Return the number of car fleets that will arrive at the destination.
`Example 1:
Input: target = 12, position = [10,8,0,5,3], speed = [2,4,1,1,3]
Output: 3
Explanation:
The cars starting at 10 (speed 2) and 8 (speed 4) become a fleet, meeting each other at 12.
The car starting at 0 does not catch up to any other car, so it is a fleet by itself.
The cars starting at 5 (speed 1) and 3 (speed 3) become a fleet, meeting each other at 6. The fleet moves at speed 1 until it reaches target.
Note that no other cars meet these fleets before the destination, so the answer is 3.
Example 2:
Input: target = 10, position = [3], speed = [3]
Output: 1
Explanation: There is only one car, hence there is only one fleet.
Example 3:
Input: target = 100, position = [0,2,4], speed = [4,2,1]
Output: 1
Explanation:
The cars starting at 0 (speed 4) and 2 (speed 2) become a fleet, meeting each other at 4. The fleet moves at speed 2.
Then, the fleet (speed 2) and the car starting at 4 (speed 1) become one fleet, meeting each other at 6. The fleet moves at speed 1 until it reaches target.`
I want to create my own solution and I think the stack is a good approach to solve this problem in a optimar solution (Possibly O(n) time complexity). The 3 test cases are being passed, but when submitting the solution, other secundary test cases are not passing like this one:
`target =
10
position =
[0,4,2]
speed =
[2,1,3]
Use Testcase
Output
2
Expected
1`
The current solution:
def carFleet(self, target: int, position: List[int], speed: List[int]) -> int:
        stack = []
        for i in range(len(position)):
            time = (target - position[i]) / speed[i]
            while stack and time >= stack[-1]:
                stack.pop()
            stack.append(time)
        return len(stack)

I think the approach that I'm taking in the while loop is the correct one (but who am i to say that if the algorithm is not passing all test cases), because with the while loop i'm removing the cars that will catch up to the cars in front of them with slower speed, so that in the end, the elements that are present in the stack are car fleets (length of the stack (O(1))). What do you guys think?
Any tips would be highly appreciated, take care :D

You're not considering that a car slows down to the speed of the car in front of it as soon as it catches up, so you cannot compare the time to reach the destination of two arbitrary cars. Instead, you can sort all the cars by position (each position is guaranteed to be unique) and keep track of the leader of the current fleet.
def carFleet(self, target: int, position: List[int], speed: List[int]) -> int:
    cars = sorted(range(len(speed)), reverse=True, key=lambda i: position[i])
    ans = len(speed) + 1
    curr = cars[0]
    for c in cars:
        if (target - position[c]) / speed[c] <= (target - position[curr]) / speed[curr]:
            ans -= 1
        else:
            curr = c
    return ans


misinterpreted that part of the problem. Thank you very much!
